# Extract values from 2d array with indices from another array (without loops)

Tags: matlab, find, indices

I have an array `[2; 3]` and a matrix `[ 1 3 4 5; 2 4 9 2]`.
Now I would like to extract the second element from the first row and the third element from the second row and thus obtain `[3 ; 9]`. I managed it to do it with a loop, but since I'm working with much larger arrays, I would like to avoid these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert each of the column subscripts (along with their row subscripts) into a [linear index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?refresh=true#f1-85511) and then use *that* to index into your matrix.

```
A = [1 3 4 5; 2 4 9 2];
cols = [2; 3];

% Compute the linear index using sub2ind
inds = sub2ind(size(A), (1:numel(cols)).', cols);

B = A(inds)
%   3   
%   9
```

Alternately, you could compute the linear indices yourself which is going to be more performant than `sub2ind`

```
B = A((cols - 1) * size(A, 1) + (1:numel(cols)).');
%   3
%   9
```

Answer (score 3):

By exploiting the [`diag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) function, you can obtain an elegant one-line solution:

```
A = [1 3 4 5; 2 4 9 2];
cols = [2; 3];

B = diag(A(:,cols))
%   3
%   9
```

---

Here is what `diag(A(:,cols))` does:

1. `A(:,cols)` selects the columns `cols` of `A`, with column `k` of `A(:,cols)` corresponding to the column `cols(k)` of `A`, giving `[3 4; 4 9]`;
2. `diag` returns the diagonal entries of this matrix, thus returning at position `k` the `k`-th diagonal element of `A(:,cols)`, which is `A(k,cols(k))`.